# What is the difference between Local and cascaded WITH CHECK OPTION clause in MySQL 8.0+

Tags: mysql, database

I came across these two clauses in the WITH CHECK OPTION which are LOCAL and CASCADED.
in the previous version of MySQL, the LOCAL option was just checking the rule for its own view. whereas the CASCADED option checks all view rules to its underlying views. You can check [that out here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).
However, this has been changed in mysql 8.0, where the LOCAL cascaded checks the rules recursively to all its underlying views. Whereas, for the CASCADED, the documentation says, "With `CASCADED`, the view `WHERE` clause is checked, then checking recurses to underlying views, adds `WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION` to them (for purposes of the check; their definitions remain unchanged), and applies the same rules".

Then how is the LOCAL different from the CASCADED?

a simple example might help me to understand as it is too confusing for me. Is anything i am not getting it correctly?

Comment: And what do you want to use it for

Comment: Not using in a real-time project but I was kinda curious about it when I came across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty rare case.

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, x int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set x = 42;

mysql> create view v1 as select * from mytable where x < 42;
```

Note `v1` does not have a CHECK OPTION. I should be able to insert a value that does not match the filtering condition of the view.

```
mysql> insert into v1 set x = 43;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now I create two views that query `v1`, one view has the local check option, the other has the cascaded check option.

```
mysql> create view v2 as select * from v1 where x >= 42 with local check option;

mysql> insert into v2 set x = 43;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

This is okay because it satisfies the condition of `v2`, and the condition of `v1` still permits non-matching values. The quality of checking only applies to the condition of `v2`.

Now the last test:

```
mysql> create view v3 as select * from v1 where x >= 42 with cascaded check option;

mysql> insert into v3 set x = 43;
ERROR 1369 (HY000): CHECK OPTION failed 'test.v3'
```

This fails even though the value satisfies the condition of `v3`. But because it cascades its check option, it changes the condition of `v1` so that it's as if that view had been defined with the check option. Thus the quality of checking cascades down to a view that did not originally have that option.

There's an example in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-check-option.html but I think the example misses the point, because in their case, `v1` is also defined with the CHECK OPTION. It does not demonstrate the difference between local and cascaded check options.